# Protractor ng-repeater element selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Trying to select the text from the first column in the first row of an ng-repeat. The html (these are rows within a table body):

```
        <tr ng-repeat="c in cars | orderBy:'-type' ">

            <!-- Type -->
            <td>{{ c.type }}</td>

            <!-- Notes -->
            <td>{{ c.notes }}</td>
        </tr>
```

The selection attempt:

```
    var type= element.all(by.repeater("c in cars| orderBy:'-date' ").
        row(0).column(0));
    type.getText()
        .then(function(text){
            console.log('ISSUED FROM: ' + text);
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? As usual, I have looked through the examples on SO (there a few for repeater), but they don't seem to work (...for me, I am sure they work and I am doing something wrong). I don't get an error, but I get nothing for "text" even though in the browser, there is clearly a string.

It looks like this when viewing source, if that helps:

```
<!-- Type -->
<td class="ng-binding">Murcielago</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`by.exactRepeater()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater) would be a better option here. Also, *`column()` should be called with a binding* passed into and, since you need a single element, use `element()`:

```
var type = element(by.exactRepeater("c in cars").row(0).column("c.type"));
expect(type.getText()).toEqual("Murcielago");
```

Comment: That worked Alec, thank you, don't know what I would do without you. Looks like you are one of the few people watching the Protractor questions.

Comment: @VSO thanks, yes, protractor tag is not very active, but it's getting more popular from day to day.